# Cómo fijar fila de encabezado en una tabla de doc generada desde Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-documentos

Estoy creando tablas en un documento de Google Doc desde Google Apps Script y me surge la duda si desde el propio código puedo hacer que la primera fila de la tabla se fije como encabezado, de manera que si la tabla ocupa varias páginas repita la fila de encabezado en cada una. Es algo que desde Doc se puede hacer pero no he encontrado la forma de definirlo desde Google Apps Script.